# Function object in boost::fusion::for_each different from std::for_each

Tags: c++, foreach, constants, boost-fusion

While upgrading to a newer compiler and resolving compiler errors I realized that `boost::fusion::for_each` requires that the function object passed in has the operator `const`.

Example from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/for_each.html):

```
struct increment
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const
    {
        ++t;
    }
};
...
vector<int,int> vec(1,2);
for_each(vec, increment());
```

This has of course not changed. I didn't realized it's different to [`std::for_each`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html), which does not require the operator to be `const`.

```
struct increment
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) // no const here!!!
    {
        ++t;
    }
};
std::vector<int> numbers;
std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), increment());
```

Is there any obvious reason for requiring `const`? I obviously cannot change that, but I'd like to understand why these two differ.

Thanks for any insights and explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Constness may be required to prevent internal state changes of the functor, since, the order of the operator() calls is not defined for each element in sequence. So, the consequent calls should not depend on each other.

Comment: looks like intuition but it makes sense ;-)

Comment: Do you have a reference where it says the order is undefined?

Comment: @murrekatt No, I don't. But also, the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/for_each.html) doesn't mention any strict order of the calls. And there is a [mailing thread](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2007/03/26355.php) which may interest you - the main idea is about performance optimizations.

Comment: @abyss.7: thanks for the mail thread. I believe a for_each means it is a strict order, not the opposite.